# writing some script in sourceQuery in DHF flow of Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

I have one requirement while running DHF flow I can't use `cts.uris` in place of sourceQuery. I want to use some script.
How can I achieve this?

I tried like this.. but not working

I have placed my script under a custom directory and calling that script in the flow.
If I run sourceQuery in qconsole it was working, but if I try to run the flow I'm getting an error.

> (Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":400, "status":"Bad Request",
> "messageCode":"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ", "message":"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: fn.error(null, 'RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ', err); --Invalid request:)

I tried like this, but it's not working

```
"sourceQuery" : "require('/custom-modules/custom/my-source-query.xqy').sourceQuery()",
"sourceQueryIsScript" : true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation indicates that field sourceQuery must be "Set sourceQuery to a string containing any script that can be passed to xdmp.eval"

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.4/flows/customizing-steps.html

Comment: Hi Andres,
I tried  by changing xqy script to sjs script still it's not working
 
 "sourceQueryIsScript" : true,
        "sourceQuery" : "require('/custom-modules/custom/myQuery.sjs').instance(1000)",

but if i run souceQuery in qconsole i was able to get uris